# Is $a \mapsto 2a$ bijective?

Tags: calculus, functions, relations

Why $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = 2x$ is not always bijective? I selected as always bijective in a quiz, it said wrong, always injective!

Comment: One question: is $R = \mathbb R$?

Comment: yes, it is R = Real Numbers Set

Comment: It is always bijective: it is surjective since any real number $x$ can be written as $x = f(\frac12 x)$, and is injective since $2x = 2y$ implies $x=y$.

Comment: If $R=\Bbb{R}$, then $f(a)=2a$ is bijective, since $$f(a)=f(b)\implies 2a=2b \implies a=b\implies f\text{ is one-one}$$
and for any $y\in\Bbb{R}$, $$f(y/2)=y\implies f\text{ is onto}$$

Comment: Exactly, I selected it as the right answer in a quiz, it said it is always injective.

Comment: Are you sure then that $R=\mathbb{R}$? Because $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ , $n \mapsto 2n$ is not a surjection since no natural number maps to say $3$.

Comment: I am sure! It says R, of course if N It is not surjective

Comment: What does "always" bijective mean ? Either it is bijective, either it is not.

Comment: Exactly again, I thought of that haha

Comment: If $R$ is an arbitrary ring rather than the real numbers then it would explain why it is not always surjective for example it is not for the integers.  However, it would not always be injective either as the ring might have characteristic $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you selected is correct since you have $A=B=\mathbb R.$

Remember that $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a bijection $\iff$

- **injective:** $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$
- **surjective:** for all $y\in B$ there is some $x\in A$ such that $f(x)=y.$

Clearly your function is injective since $f(x)=f(y) \iff 2x=2y\iff x=y$ and it is also surjective since taking $x=\frac{y}{2}\in A$ we obtain $f(x)=2x=2\frac{y}{2}=y.$ Thus your function is a bijection.

If instead you had $A=B=\mathbb N$, then the function will still be injective, but it will NOT be surjective. This is because in this case there is no $x\in\mathbb N$ such that $f(x)=2n+1$ for some $n\in\mathbb Z_{\geq0}$ for example.

Moreover if you had $\forall x\in \mathbb R$ $f(x)=b$ for some constant $b$ (and $y\in\mathbb R$), then $f(x)$ is neither injective nor surjective.